# Remote sql file run from PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Apologies for this question but I'm unsure of the wording to search for an answer

I have a file `'C:\Dir Name\Mike.sql`' (which spools output to a text file. Due to complex business logic which I don't fancy writing, I'd like to continue to use this file

Within SQL*Plus, I can run it using `@'C:\Dir Name\Mike.sql arg1 arg2...'`

How can I achieve the same thing from PL/SQL?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772500/how-to-run-sql-scripts-from-a-pl-sql-procedure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830427/run-script-from-pl-sql-block

Comment: If the script indeed uses `SPOOL` there is no way you can use it from within a stored procedure - `SPOOL` is an internal SQL*Plus command, not a SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - I'm starting to think I need to investigate UTL_FILE or something. Will I be able to write to the C: drive of machine from the PL/SQL or is the script executed on the server with no concept of my client machine?

Comment: @Mike - the server doesn't know anything about the client's filesystem; that applies to an PL/SQL including UTL_FILE, data pump, etc. Unless you have a shared drive or a remote mount, which is unlikely. You can't read the script from your local drive, and you can't write output to your local drive. SQL*Plus can with it's internal commands (i.e. spool) only because it is running locally as a client application.

Comment: @AlexPoole - I forsee a conversation with my admin to get a network share mapped/mounted to our Oracle server! Many thanks for confirming my suspicions! Mike Poole (no relation I'm sure!)

Comment: Even if you *can* load that script using PL/SQL it will **not** work from within a stored procedure because SQL*PLus commands **only** work in SQL*Plus